# What are the attributes that are need to Send with this FEDEX shipping script?

Tags: php, fedex

could any one please tell me what are the attributes that are send with $ship_data ?

I am too confused about it.

I know that ORIGIN ADDRESS, DESTINATION ADDRESS, NAME etc.. need to be send.

But how the data should be aligned. Like name is FIRST, address is SECOND etc...

Any help will be useful

**>

> // create new fedex object $fed = new
>   FedExDC('#########','#########');
>
> **$ship_data = array( 75=>   'LBS', 
>        16=>   'Ma' , 
>        13=>   '44 Main street' , 
>        5=>    '312 stuart st', 
>        1273=> '01', 
>        1274=> '01',
>        18=>   '6173335555', 
>        15=>   'Boston',
>        23=>   '1',
>        9=>    '02134',
>        183=>  '6175556985',
>        8=>    'MA',
>        117=>  'US',
>        17=>   '02116',
>        50=>   'US',
>        4=>    'Vermonster LLC',
>        7=>    'Boston',
>        1369=> '1',
>        12=>   'Jay Powers',
>        1333=> '1',
>        1401=> '1.0',
>        116=>  1,
>        68=>  'USD',
>        1368=> 1,
>        1369=> 1,
>        1370=> 5
>       );**
>
> // Ship example $ship_Ret =
>   $fed->ship_express($ship_data);
>
> if ($error = $fed->getError()) {
>       echo "ERROR :". $error; } else {
>       // Save the label to disk
>       $fed->label('mylabel.png');
>
> }
>
> /* tracking example
>
> $track_Ret = $fed->track( array(
>       29 => 790344664540, ));
>
> echo $fed->debug_str. "\n
> "; echo
>   "Price ".$ship_Ret[1419];*/ echo
>   "
>
> ```
> "; if ($error =
>   $fed->getError()) {
>       die("ERROR: ". $error); }  else  {
>       // decode and save label
>       $fed->label('myLabel.png');
>       echo $fed->debug_str. "\n
> ";
>       echo "\n\n";
>       echo "Price $".$ship_Ret[1419];
>       echo "\n";
>       echo "Tracking# ".$ship_Ret[29]; } echo "
> ```
>
> ";
>
> ?>**

Thanks

Fero

Answer (score 0):

Try this [PHP Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/1276.html) it has been developed to process transactions with FedEx's Ship Manager using the Direct Connection API. It can be used for all transactions that the API can support.

For more detailed information please referer to FedEx's documentation located at their website.

http://www.fedex.com/us/solutions/wis/

Comment: Thanks Pasts. But i am already using the same code which you mentioned. There i want to know what are the inputs i need to pass in $shipdata.

Comment: Take a look at Page 66 of this http://fedex.com/us/solutions/wis/pdf/xml_transguide.pdf?link=4

Comment: I saw the link you mentioned.. But i should know from the above code what are the data such as $ship_data = array(75=> 'LBS', 16=> 'Ma'.... 1370=> 5 ); In this array what is 75 and what is LBS(Means what parameter should be here. Exampled country or first name like that what should be here for all the values in $ship_data) and what is 16 and what is MA. This is exactly what i want. If i get those i hope i can able to complete the task. Kindly help me regarding this issue.